# FTPClient(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient) is not able to retrieve large xml file

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have three different sizes of files in my ftp location with 2KB, 76KB and 216MB. I have to process these files one by one, I am able to retrieve the first two files easily using the retrieveFileStream(FILE_NAME_HERE) but when it comes to process the third file, it takes forever (my application keeps hanging) with no results. I have to get the files as input stream and make jaxb object out of them later. This is the utility method which I am using to get the input stream:

```
public InputStream convertToInputStream(FTPFile file) throws IOException{
        if(file!=null){
            InputStream is=ftp.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());

            ftp.completePendingCommand();
            return is;

        }

        return null;
```

Can you please point what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What are you doing with the InputStream? Writing to hard drive? Or keep all the stuff in memory? Tried -Xmx jvm option to increase heap size? And in which line of code does it "hang"?

Comment: I have to keep it in memory to Unmarshal it first, and if the unmarshalling is successful then I have to store that stream(in the form of file) in a network drive, I cannot just store it first because if I am not able to process that input stream file, I should not be saving it. That's the requirement. It fails at `ftp.completePendingCommand();` I put the sysout command right before and after `InputStream is=ftp.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());` and I can see both sysouts being written but it just does not move forward in case of bigger files for `completePendingCommand`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably to late to help you (might help someone else though) but when I had a similar problem (both upload and download) I was able to resolve it by setting the buffer size, setBufferSize(), after connecting see the code snippet below. This took my uploads from 12min for a 240MB file to 18seconds with a similar improvement on the download.

I have the BUFFER_SIZE set to 32768 but 8192 worked almost as well, especially for sub 50MB files after which there was a slight improvement with the larger size.

```
if (this.ftpClient.isConnected())
{
    this.ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    this.ftpClient.setBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
    try
    {
        this.ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        throw Throwables.propagate(e);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.